# Autopopulation in picklist on same page

Tags: case

I have a requirement in which i am working on case object. I have a standard field Account Name and custom field -Account Owner(lookup on user) and Account Type(picklist) on Case object.
On selecting a value into Account Name corresponding value of Account's owner name and Account type should be autopopulated.. Is it possible through standard fuctionality or need to go for VF page .. Pls Suggest..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible through standard functionality. You can create a VF page to get the details of account on the change of AccountName and refresh the related details on your page.

Comment: Ok i will try it out [:)]